Is AG-Grid "Full With Row" except pinned columns possible?
Is there any way a Full Width Row can span all columns except for the ones that are pinned left and right?
First of all, I use Angular for this.
I have a grid containing article rows on an order.
The first three columns are pinned to the left (a checkbox, an icon and a row number).
The last two columns are pinned to the right (two different clickable icons).
In between there are a lot of columns specifying the article, quantity, prices and so on.
But, I also have a specific row type that you can add, instead of an article row, a textrow.
The textrow should span over all columns except for the pinned ones. The textrow is used to add a line of text instead of an article.
The problem is that it is not the first "unpinned" column it is the second.
The first column is an article selector (Lev.art.nr in the image). The second column is a description of the article (Benämning) and it's that column I use to span the entire grid.
Currently I'm using column span to make it work, but that only spans to the right.
So I can't make it span over the column to the left.
If I use Full Width Row, it will also span over the pinned ones, which is not as expected.
There is an example in the docs called "Embedded Full Width Rows", but then all pinned columns are merged into one, so it's not what I want.
Order rows
